# Need help using an image as a plot in an Action Map using Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, scatter-plot, apexcharts

This is for a sports-related chart that we're making - action maps against the goal frame. This gives an idea of where against the frame of the goal that shots/saves were made. The Apexcharts library is being used for this.

Now, currently, my dev isn't being able to use custom designed images for the plots and is just using a circle with a particular gradient. Image:
[Goal Map - No Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljpro.jpg)

Instead of these circles, we require [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scxlm.jpg) images to be used instead. However, when one of them was used as a test, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5kHr.jpg) happens.

For different kinds of plots, we have different images. The plotting is all correct, we're just not being able to use images.

I've shared the code that is being employed right now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="prev-vis-cont goal-map-img" style="width: 50%;height: 20%; background-color: grey">
    <div id="previous_goal_map"></div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var img = 'img2.jpeg';

    var options = {
      chart: {
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        type: 'scatter',
        zoom: {
          enabled: false
        }


      },

      markers: {
        size: 10,

      },


      //colors:["#fff"],
      // colors: ['#76FF03'],
      // fill: {
      //     type: 'gradient',
      //     opacity:0.7,
      // },
      fill: {
        type: 'image',
        opacity: 1,
        image: {
          src: [img, img.img, img, img, img],
          width: 35,
          height: 35
        }
      },
      series: [{
          name: "R Shot Wide",
          data: [7.21, 5.64]
        },
        {
          name: "R Shot Wide",
          data: [0.97, 1.22]
        },
        {
          name: "R Shot On",
          data: [1.42, 3.96]
        },
        {
          name: "R Goal",
          data: [3.35, .78]
        },
        {
          name: "R Shot Wide",
          data: [4.27, 8.37]
        }
      ],
      xaxis: {

        tickAmount: 8,
        min: 0,
        max: 8,
        labels: {
          show: false
        },
        axisBorder: {
          show: false
        },
        axisTicks: {
          show: false
        },
        crosshairs: {
          show: false
        }

      },
      yaxis: {

        tickAmount: 5,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        labels: {
          show: true
        }
      },

      legend: {
        show: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,

        x: {
          show: false,
          title: false,

        },
        y: {
          formatter: function (val, index) {
            return ''
          },
          title: {
            formatter: (seriesName) => seriesName,
          },

        }


      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },

      grid: {
        show: false,

      }


    }

    console.log(options);
    $("#previous_goal_map").html('');
    var chart = new ApexCharts(
      document.querySelector("#previous_goal_map"),
      options
    );

    chart.render();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in ApexCharts.

I tried using images in the scatter chart as you can see in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/YgWRoL), but the image dimensions don't respect the `markers.size`.
So, I am going to open a ticket on GitHub and will update this answer once the fix is done and released.

*Disclaimer: I am the creator of ApexCharts*

Comment: I guess you are the perfect person for this post to have reached! 

Thanks a lot. Any idea on how long this might take? We managed to edit the code a little bit and have got a slightly different, [yet flawed output](https://imgur.com/4HMFs1k). The issue is that we plan on displaying these charts to a few people in ~ 1 week. Any suggestions on a best alternative if this doesn't get done in time?

Comment: You can expect a release on the upcoming weekend.

Comment: Apexcharts 3.6.1 released which fixes this issue